# Using jQuery to append a glyphicon - not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm using jQuery to append a glyphicon to a header of a question form I'm creating, based on which question you're working on in the form. Here is my code:

```
 var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(payload);

 var headerData = jsonObj.fields;     

 for (var i = 0; i < headerData.length; i++) {

    $nr = $('.nr' + i);
    $qnr = $('.qnr' + i);

    $nr.on("mousedown",function() {
      $('.glyphicon-saved').remove();
      $('.glyphicon-pencil').remove();
      $qnr.append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
    });

    $nr.on("mouseleave", function() {
      $('.glyphicon-saved').remove();
      $('.glyphicon-pencil').remove();
      $qnr.append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>');

    }); 

  }
```

I'm creating the html by parsing json data:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < headerData.length; i++) {

        if(jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "sFormName") {

          body.unshift("<div class='panel panel-default panel-element main-heading'><div class='panel-heading'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].label + "</div></div>")

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].required == true ) {

          body.push("<div class='panel panel-default panel-element question-element'><div class='panel-heading question-heading qnr" + i + "'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].label + "<label style='color: red'>&nbsp*</label></div>"); 

        } else {

          body.push("<div class='panel panel-default panel-element question-element'><div class='panel-heading question-heading qnr" + i + "'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].label + "</div>"); 

        }                    

        if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionTextBig") {

         body.push("<div class='panel-body'><textarea class='large-text form-control nr" + i + "'></textarea></div></div>");   

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionText") {

          body.push("<div class='panel-body'><input class='form-control text-small nr" + i + "' type='text'></div></div>");

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionMultiBegin") {

          var data = jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options;

          body.push('<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"><tr class="tr-header"><th>Mjög sammála / Strongly agree</th><th>Frekar sammála / Agree</th><th>Hvorki né / Indifferent</th><th>Frekar ósammála / Disagree</th><th>Mjög ósammála / Strongly disagree</th><th>Staðhæfing / Statement</th></tr>')  

          for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            body.push("<tr><td><input type='radio' name='radio" + j + "' class = 'nr" + i + "></td><td><input type='radio' name='radio" + j + "'></td><td><input type='radio' name='radio" + j + "'></td><td><input type='radio' name='radio" + j + "'></td><td><input type='radio' name='radio" + j + "'></td><td>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[j].label + "</td></tr>");
          }  

          body.push('</table></div>')          

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionParagraph") {

          body.push("<div class='panel-body paragraph-text'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.description + "</div></div>");

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionDropdown") {

          var data = jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options;

          body.push("<div class='panel-body'><div class='dropdown'><button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'><span data-bind='label'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[0].label + "</span>&nbsp;<span class='caret'></span></button><ul class='dropdown-menu'>");


          for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
              body.push("<li><a href='#' class='nr" +  i + "'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[j].label + "</a></li>");
            } 

          body.push("</ul></div></div></div>");

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionRadio") {

          var data = jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options;

          body.push("<div class='panel-body'><div class='radio'><div class='controls nr" + i + "'>");

          for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
              body.push("<label class='radio' value='option'><input type='radio' name='radio'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[j].label + "</label>");
            } 

           if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.include_other_option == true) {
              body.push("<label class='radio' value='option'><input type='radio' name='radio' class='other-input'> Annað / Other<input class='form-control other-text' type='text'>")
            }


          body.push("</div></div></div></div>");

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "Registration") {

          body.push("<div class='panel-body'>");
          body.push("<div class='form-group'><form class='reg-form nr" + i + "' role='form'><div class='form-group'><label for='email'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[0].label + "</label>");
          body.push("<input type'email' class='form-control' id='email'></div>");
          body.push("<div class='form-group'><form class='reg-form nr" + i + "' role='form'><div class='form-group'><label for='pwd'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[1].label + "</label>");
          body.push("<input type'password' class='form-control' id='pwd'></div>");
          body.push("<div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox'> Muna mig / Remember me</label></div></form></div>"); 
          body.push("</div></div></div>") 
      }

    var htmlMarkup = body.join('');

    $(container).html(htmlMarkup);
}
```

So my problem is, the selectors for $nr and $qnr are both working correctly (I can see they're selecting the right data with console.log), however, the $qnr.append() doesn't work and I'm getting no error message so I am lost as to why. Does anyone have an idea of a solution to this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Mind posting your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you create your html first, then use a closure:-

```js
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(payload);

var headerData = jsonObj.fields;

for (var i = 0; i < headerData.length; i++) {

  (function(i) {

    $nr = $('.nr' + i);
    $qnr = $('.qnr' + i);

    $nr.on("mousedown", function() {
      $('.glyphicon-saved').remove();
      $('.glyphicon-pencil').remove();
      $qnr.append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
    });

    $nr.on("mouseleave", function() {
      $('.glyphicon-saved').remove();
      $('.glyphicon-pencil').remove();
      $qnr.append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>');

    });

  })(i);

}
```

Without a closure, $`qnr` will always be the last element in the `for` iteration.